# Cohomology of the structure sheaf of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

I need to compute the euler characteristic $\chi(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1})$ of the structure sheaf of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ (the product of the projective complex line with itself). I suppose that to do so, I could use Kunneth formula and a bit of Hodge theory, but I'm not familiar with this subject.

Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know Serre duality and the canonical bundle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Euler-Poincaré characteristic $\chi(V)=\chi(V,\mathcal O_V)$ of the structure sheaf of a smooth projective variety   is called the Hirzebruch arithmetic genus and it is multiplicative : $$\chi(V\times W)=\chi(V)\times \chi(W)$$ This immediately solves your problem: $\chi(\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1)=\chi(\mathbb P^1)\times \chi(\mathbb P^1)=1\times 1=1$ .

Proofs can be found in Hartshorne: Exercise I, 7.2 page54 and Exercise III, 5.3 page230.
And [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/92807/450)  is a related post.

**Edit: a variant**
The [Segre morphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding) embeds the variety $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$ as a quadric $Q\subset\mathbb P^3$.
The Severi arithmetic genus of $Q$ is given by $p_a(Q)=\binom{2-1}{3}=0$ (Hartshorne, Chapter I, Exercise 7.2, page54) .
Since $\chi(Q)=1+(-1)^{dim Q}\cdot p_a(Q)$, we get again $\chi(Q)=1+(-1)^2 \cdot 0=1$